# "... said Sally" or "... Sally said"?

Tags: word-order, inversion

I have always hesitated about the order S+V or V+S after a quote. For example, in the following sentence should I write "... said Sally" or "... Sally said"?

> "If everything is coming your way, then you’re in the wrong lane," ***Sally said/said Sally*** packing her things.

I would also appreciate an explanation of how the use you think is correct came to be established as a rule.

Comment: [related](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49862/is-there-a-difference-between-joe-said-and-said-joe), and I liked [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/246858/when-would-you-use-said-he)

Comment: Both are 'correct' - it's just a matter of stylistic choice,.